# append a json object to an array within my postgres table

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, groovy

I have a postgres table which stores some JSON using Groovy sql, I want to append an object to my 'players' array to add a new player to my database. At the moment I am trying this.I try to target my 'players' array and append my new json which comes from the server. This gives me an error

> .PSQLException: ERROR: function array_append(jsonb, jsonb) does not
>   exist

I think I may be getting this error has the first param needs to be an array not jsonb, is there a way to target the array in my db so it comes back as an array? Or is there a better way to append this object to my array?

```
  sql.executeUpdate("""
            UPDATE site_content
            SET content = array_append(content->'playersContainer'->'players', '${json}'::jsonb);
            where id = :id
        """, id: player.teamId)
}
```

Here is my JSON

```
"playersContainer": {
        "players": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Nick Pocock",
                "teamName": "Shire Soldiers",
                "bio" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla imperdiet lorem tellus, in bibendum sem dignissim sed. Etiam eu elit sit amet lacus accumsan blandit sed ut dolor. Mauris vel dui non nisi vestibulum commodo vel id magna. Donec egestas magna in tincidunt mollis. Fusce mauris arcu, rhoncus ut lacus sed, fermentum ultrices elit. In sollicitudin at ex dapibus vestibulum. Pellentesque congue, est id lobortis viverra, mauris lectus pharetra orci, ut suscipit nisl purus vehicula est. Aliquam suscipit non velit vel feugiat. Quisque nec dictum augue.",
                "ratings": [
                    1,
                    5,
                    6,
                    9
                ],
                "assists": 17,
                "manOfTheMatches": 20,
                "cleanSheets": 1,
                "data": [
                    3,
                    2,
                    3,
                    5,
                    6
                ],
                "totalGoals": 19

            }
}
```

My column is called content which holds the JSONb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 9.5:

```
UPDATE site_content
            SET content = jsonb_set(content, '{playersContainer,players}'::text[], content->'playersContainer'->'players' || '${json}'::jsonb);
            where id = :id
```

Comment: I get this error  because: ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb || jsonb
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 164

Comment: || jsonb Concatenate two jsonb values into a new jsonb value (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html  )

Comment: You use 9.5 or 9.4 postgresql?

Comment: I have 9.5 installed on my machine

Comment: For 9.4 does not exists neither json[b]_set nor ||

Comment: I recently upgraded to 9.5 do i have to anything to my databases to use 9.5?

Comment: Do you restart db? could you provide what write psql when you connect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135001/discussion-between-roman-tkachuk-and-nick-pocock).

Comment: could you please vote Up + mark as Accepted my answer.

Comment: Answer worked perfectly after reinstalling postgres 9.5, thank you!