# Appending new object to JSONB in postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I trying to add new object to my table in one column called **PARAM**, inside of that column I have:

```
{"array1": [
    {"array2": [
        {"objId": 1, "data": false, "repeat": 1},
        {"objId": 2, "data": false, "repeat": 1}
    ]}
]}
```

I want to add new object to **array2** I am using that query

```
UPDATE table
SET param = jsonb_set(
        param::jsonb,
        array['array1'],
        (param->'array1'->>'array2')::jsonb || jsonb_build_object('objId', '3','data', 'false','repeat', '1')::jsonb)
WHERE ...
```

but instead getting

```
{"array1": [
    {"array2": [
        {"objId": 1, "data": false, "repeat": 1},
        {"objId": 2, "data": false, "repeat": 1},
        {"objId": 3, "data": false, "repeat": 1}
    ]}
]}
```

my **PARAM** become null. Anyone can solve that?

[I have based my solution on that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233542/appending-pushing-and-removing-from-a-json-array-in-postgresql-9-5)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select 
      jsonb_set(
                param::jsonb,
                '{array1,0,array2}',
                jsonb_extract_path(param, 'array1','0','array2')::jsonb ||
                jsonb_build_object('objId', '3','data', 'false','repeat', '1')::jsonb
               )
```

you can put where clause as per your requirement