# Append a value to json array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a postgresql table `profile` with columns (`username`, `friends`). `username` is a string and `friends` is a json type and has the current values `["Mary", "Bob]`. I want to append an item at the end of the array so it is `["Mary", "Bob", "Alice"]`

I am currently have tried:

```sql
UPDATE profile SET friends = friends || '["Alice"]'::jsonb WHERE username = 'David';
```

This yields the error:

```
[ERROR] 23:56:23 error: operator does not exist: json || jsonb
```

I tried changing the first expression to include `json` instead of `jsonb` but I then got the error:

```
[ERROR] 00:06:25 error: operator does not exist: json || json
```

Other answers seem to suggesst the || operator is indeed a thing, e.g.:
[Appending (pushing) and removing from a JSON array in PostgreSQL 9.5+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233542/appending-pushing-and-removing-from-a-json-array-in-postgresql-9-5)

How do I append an item to the end of a json array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data type [`json`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) is much more limited than [`jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html). Use `jsonb` instead of `json` and the solution you found simply works.

While stuck with `json`, a possible workaround is to cast to `jsonb` and back:

```sql
UPDATE profile
SET    friends = (friends::jsonb || '["Alice"]')::json
WHERE  username = 'David';
```

You might use an explicit type for `jsonb '["Alice"]'`, too, but that's optional. While the expression is unambiguous like that, the untyped string literal will be coerced to `jsonb` automatically. If you instead provide a typed value in place of `'["Alice"]'`, the explicit cast may be required.

If `friends` can be `NULL`, you'll want to define what should happen then. Currently, nothing happens. Or, to be precise, an update that doesn't change the `NULL` value.

Then again, if you only have simple arrays of strings, consider the plain [Postgres array type `text[]`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) instead.