# How to push a JSON object to a array in jsonb column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, append, jsonb

I m new in using jsonb in postgresql.

```
I have a following structure 

      [
          {
              "Id":1,
              "Name":"Emilia"
          },
          {
              "Id":2,
              "Name":"sophia"
          },
          {
              "Id":3,
              "Name":"Anna"
          },
          {
              "Id":4,
              "Name":"Marjoe"
          }
      ]
```

1. This structure is stored in jsonb column (items).I need to append `{"Id":5,"Name":"Linquin"}` in this array.and set it back to jsonb column items.

I need something like this.

```
     [
          {
              "Id":1,
              "Name":"Emilia"
          },
          {
              "Id":2,
              "Name":"sophia"
          },
          {
              "Id":3,
              "Name":"Anna"
          },
          {
              "Id":4,
              "Name":"Marjoe"
          },
          {
              "Id":5,
              "Name":"Linquin"
          }
      ]
```

2. And please let me know any  way to delete objects based on id....

Appreciate any help.Thanks...

Comment: what's your postgres version?..

Comment: the version of postgres is PostgreSQL 9.6.1 .thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For add new element to `jsonb` array, as @VaoTsun said you can use concatenate

```
select j||'{"Id":5,"Name":"Linquin"}'::jsonb as newjosn   from (
    select '[
      {
          "Id":1,
          "Name":"Emilia"
      },
      {
          "Id":2,
          "Name":"sophia"
      },
      {
          "Id":3,
          "Name":"Anna"
      },
      {
          "Id":4,
          "Name":"Marjoe"
      }
    ]'::jsonb as j
) t
```

for removing element based on id, one way is this: (for example remove element which `id=2`)

```
select to_jsonb(array_agg(lst)) as newjson from (
    select  jsonb_array_elements('[
      {
          "Id":1,
          "Name":"Emilia"
      },
      {
          "Id":2,
          "Name":"sophia"
      },
      {
          "Id":3,
          "Name":"Anna"
      },
      {
          "Id":4,
          "Name":"Marjoe"
      }
    ]'::jsonb) as lst
) t
where lst->'Id' <> '2'
```

So, this method just gets all json array values as records of json elements, then selects all elements except element which have `id=2`, and then makes again json array from selected records.

Note, if you need actually update column, then this method requires that table should have unique/identity column (`id` column normally), because every json array should be grouped by its own `id` column. (Don't mix this `id` with your json arrays `Id` field).

Answer (score 6):

Use the concatenation operator || to append an element to an array:

```
UPDATE s101
SET j = j || '{"Id":5,"Name":"Linquin"}'::jsonb
WHERE id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

here is answer working for version >= [9.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) ([9.4 method was introduced here earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30714198/5315974))

to update jsonb value, you need to run `update set column = new_value where ...`

to construct new value you can use `jsonb_set` if you know the exact index

, or just `||` operator:

```
t=# select jsonb_set(j,'{5}','{"Id":5, "Name":"x"}'),j||'{"Id":5, "Name":"x"}' from s101;
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
jsonb_set | [{"Id": 1, "Name": "Emilia"}, {"Id": 2, "Name": "sophia"}, {"Id": 3, "Name": "Anna"}, {"Id": 4, "Name": "Marjoe"}, {"Id": 5, "Name": "x"}]
?column?  | [{"Id": 1, "Name": "Emilia"}, {"Id": 2, "Name": "sophia"}, {"Id": 3, "Name": "Anna"}, {"Id": 4, "Name": "Marjoe"}, {"Id": 5, "Name": "x"}]
```

to delete array item use `-` (Assuming Id key is accurate you should use Id-1 math to get the index):

```
t=# select j - 3 from s101;
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
?column? | [{"Id": 1, "Name": "Emilia"}, {"Id": 2, "Name": "sophia"}, {"Id": 3, "Name": "Anna"}]
```

my sample build:

```
t=# create table s101(j jsonb);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 37.734 ms
t=# insert into s101 select  ' [
t'#           {
t'#               "Id":1,
t'#               "Name":"Emilia"
t'#           },
t'#           {
t'#               "Id":2,
t'#               "Name":"sophia"
t'#           },
t'#           {
t'#               "Id":3,
t'#               "Name":"Anna"
t'#           },
t'#           {
t'#               "Id":4,
t'#               "Name":"Marjoe"
t'#           }
t'#       ]'::jsonb;
INSERT 0 1
Time: 1.070 ms
```

Comment: this works if i know the index to append.What if i dont know the index. How to do this.What comes inside jsonb_set method??.And for delete what if i want to delete only the 3rd object but i need to keep the 4th object.Thanks....

Comment: to append without index, use '||' - it is in the answer. to delete only 3rd, use `jsonb_col - 2` as per formula in answer (Id-1)